# rewrite model not working

Tags: magento-1.9, error, overrides, model, php-7

ihave problem again with my rewrite, i tried create rewrite model on my lesson
app/code/local/Lesson/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lesson_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lesson_Test>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Lesson_Test_Model_Customer</product>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Lesson/Test/Model/Customer.php

```
<?php
class Lesson_Test_Model_Customer  extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{
    public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        if ($this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name.'22222222';
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Lesson_all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lesson_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lesson_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

i try access

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/lesson 
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/customer/customer
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/customer/product
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/lesson/customer/customer
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/lesson/customer/product
```

the all of this is Whoops, our bad..., thank you :)

Comment: Try this url: `http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/customer/account`

Comment: thanks @AdarshKhatri but it still not work

Comment: what you want? want to rewrite model class or controller clasa?

Comment: i want rewrite model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per as, your code you want to rewrite class **Mage_Customer_Model_Customer**.

But in `config.xml`, you try to rewrite  model class `Mage_Customer_Model_Product` and in d*efault magento this class does not exist*. I sure you want to rewrite class ***Mage_Customer_Model_Customer***. So, you should

**Change**

```
<product>Lesson_Test_Model_Customer</product>
```

**to**

```
 <customer>Lesson_Test_Model_Customer</customer>
```

at *config.xml*

Comment: thank you  @Amitbera, but i dont look something happen
if i access `http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/customer/account` like @AdarshKhatri said, i can't look `22222222` message

Comment: you have loggedin at system or not?when $Customer->getName()  will called then it see the result

Comment: yes i login on system, on contact information i look this message
`Contact Information
Edit

gufran efendi loves Magento
diabukansaya@gmail.com
Change Password` i think a can look some message like `gufran efendi 2222222 loves Magento`

Comment: hoho i'm so stupid, i have a duplicate file about rewrite model, i delete other file and it working, thanks @Amitbera :)